# pygtk cellrenderertoggle is not checked

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, toggle, pygtk

I have the following code:

```
self.db='checks.db'
self.con = lite.connect(self.db)
self.cur = self.con.cursor()
self.q_oblig_initial='SELECT data_plirotees.rowid as rowid,recdate,bank,amount,dueto,gto,plirstatus FROM data_plirotees WHERE plirstatus=0 ORDER BY dueto ASC'
self.store_oblig = gtk.ListStore(int,str,str,str,str,str,bool)
self.cur.execute(q_oblig)
self.data_oblig=self.cur.fetchall()
for value in self.data_oblig:
    if value[6]==0:
        plir=False
    elif value[6]==1:
        plir=True     
self.store_oblig.append([value[0],datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(value[1])).strftime('%d/%m/%Y'),value[2],"%.2f" %(value[3]),datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(value[4])).strftime('%d/%m/%Y'),value[5],plir])`
```

which gets data from a sqlite database and puts it in a liststore and,

```
rendererToggle.connect("toggled", self.on_cell_toggled)
column_toggle = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Καλύφθηκε", rendererToggle, active=1)
column_toggle.set_fixed_width(10)
treeView_oblig.append_column(column_toggle)
```

which has to show it in a column where `true` should show a checked toggle/checkbox and `false` should show un-checked.

Unfortunately this doesn't happen.
The checkbox needs not to be active (i don't want it to be able to toggle) but by clicking on the treeview row it opens a new window (where a checkbutton is checked or not accordingly). From that I understand that the `true/false` value is contained there somewhere but it is not presented visually.

Can someone show me where I'm wrong?

I didn't post the whole program 'cause it would be too big and perhaps misguiding...

Comment: Furthermote when running the program I get `Warning: unable to set property 'active' of type 'gboolean' from value of type 'gchararray'
  gtk.main()`

Comment: 1) Can you post the code that creates `self.store_oblig`? 2) You don't need to post your whole program; a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will suffice. 3) To create code blocks in the Markdown, simply prefix each line with four spaces; no need to use ` everywhere. That's for inline code, `like this`.

Comment: I edited the question in a more readable way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.store_oblig = gtk.ListStore(int,str,str,str,str,str,bool)
```

This line creates a GtkListStore where each column is of a different type. The columns are numbered from left to right, starting at 0:

```
self.store_oblig = gtk.ListStore(int,str,str,str,str,str,bool)
                   column number 0   1   2   3   4   5   6
```

You create your GtkTreeViewColumn with this:

```
column_toggle = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Καλύφθηκε", rendererToggle, active=1)
```

This says that the column's cell renderer should get the value of its `active` property from column 1 of the model (in this case, the list store). And the `active` property expects a `bool`.

But if you look back above, column 1 isn't a `bool`, but rather a `string`! So what you really wanted was `active=6`, not `active=1`. (Your code to add to the list store, on the other hand, seems correct.)

This is what the warning `Warning: unable to set property 'active' of type 'gboolean' from value of type 'gchararray' gtk.main()` is trying to tell you; `gchararray` is (one of) GLib's internal name(s) for a string.

Comment: It was that simple!  Too bad that it was not in the reference...Many thanks!

Comment: Yeah; GtkTreeView is a little weird because it requires understanding a whole lot of GObject and GTK+ at once; in this case, the snag is how properties are mapped to columns of the data stores. The moment when things finally makes sense, however, makes working with GtkTreeView in the future *that* much better =P